# graphical representation in android

Tags: android, graph, charts

I stumbled upon [this](http://android.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/35-android-apps-to-monitor-usage-stats-and-tweak-system-utilities/) site today and found it quite intriguing.. Some of these apps have really stunning display of data, especially the norton mobile utilities. I want to graphically represent the information in my android application. I have researched a lot about graph librarioes available for android and have used chartdroid and achartengine, but still am not satisfied with the end result.

Which is the best charting library for android available for free?

Answer (score 1):

They are probably using custom views overrinding the onDraw method to plot lines, shapes and paths using the canvas or the surface of the view.

Have a look http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/